# Laravel session

Tags: session, laravel, middleware

I have done projects laravel shopping cart when clicking on the product detail page will open and click the add to cart sends the id to CartController @ index. I then access the database and retrieve product information and I put on the session. Then I bought other products but my older products lost in session when I turn the page. Who can help me thanks

Comment: Post your code. How can we know what's wrong with your code if we can't see it??

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't add this to existed array in session, but replace it.

Should do it this way:

```
$products = Session::get('products', array());  // get existed products or empty array
$products[] = $newProduct;                      // add new product to list
Session::put('products', $products);            // put all products to session
```

Comment: Thank .I check this after 1 hour please help me if you know anything.

Comment: Do you keep informations for 1 hour or more? Maybe you should use cookies for it. Sessions are for short-lived informations.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code for cart
public function addItem($ids,Request $request){

```
    $data = Product::find($ids)->toArray();

    $name =$data['name'];
    $price = $data['price'];
    $cart = $request->session()->get('cart');

    if($cart==null){
        $cart['quantity'][$ids] = 1;
        $cart['price'][$ids] = $price;
        $cart['name'][$ids] = $name;
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }else{
       if(array_key_exists($ids,$cart['quantity'])){
            $cart['quantity'][$ids] += 1;
            $cart['price'][$ids] = $price * $cart['quantity'][$ids];
             $cart['name'][$ids] = $name;
        }else{

            $cart['quantity'][$ids] = 1;
            $cart['price'][$ids] = $price;
            $cart['name'][$ids] = $name;
        }
         $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }





}
```